# Why sorting a vector of strings with generic lambda doesn't work?

Tags: string, sorting, c++17, c++20, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool sortByName(const auto& first, const auto& second) {
    return first < second;
}

void print(const auto& vec) {
    for(const auto& s : vec)
    cout << s << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector vec2 = {"sam", "zach", "adam", "peter"};
    print(vec2);

    auto cmp = [](const auto& s1, const auto& s2) {
        return s1 < s2;
    };
    std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), cmp);          // line (1)
    print(vec2);

    auto cmp2 = [](const string& s1, const string& s2) {
        return s1 < s2;
    };
    std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), cmp2);         // line (2)
    print(vec2);
}
```

For the above code snippet, the results are as below,

1. std::sort with cmp2 sorts the vector i.e. {adam, peter, sam, zach,}
2. std::sort with cmp keeps the elements of vector in same order, as the original vector i.e. {sam, zach, adam, peter,}

Why do we have to explicitly provide the type i.e. "string" in cmp2 to make this sort work?

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector vec2 = {"sam", "zach", "adam", "peter"};
```

This makes `vec2` into a `std::vector<const char*>`.

You are therefore comparing `const char*` in the generic lambda and not what the pointers are actually pointing at.

In order to make it work without converting the `const char*`s to `std::string`s (or better, `std::string_view`s), you could use `std::strcmp`:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

auto cmp = [](const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    return std::strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
};
```

Comment: @JeJo :-) Indeed! I already forgot about this and it's only 4 hours old :-)

Answer (score 2):

That is because in the line `vector vec2 = {"sam", "zach", "adam", "peter"}`, you didn't specify the type of the element of the vector, and the type is deduced from the initializer. Since you used string literals (`const char[]`), the type of `vec2` is deduced to be `std::vector<const char*>` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`.

Then later when you define `auto cmp = [](const auto& s1, const auto& s2)`, you are asking the compiler to deduce the types of s1 and s2 again. By using the lambda in `std::sort`, the type is deduced to the `value_type` of `std::vector<const char*>`, so you are really comparing two `const char*`, which are pointer comparisons and comparison of unrelated pointers are undefined behavior, meaning anything can happen.

When you use the form `[](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)`, the `const char*` stored in the vector are converted to temporary `std::string`s before comparing, and the comparison between two `std::string`s are well-defined, giving the expected result.

As a side note, do not use `using namespace std` especially if you are just starting to learn C++.([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have enough reputations to cast a vote.
Bdw, I don't use std namespace directly in my code but as it was a sample code for stack overflow I used it that way.

Comment: @SandeshK3112 No worries. I put my vote on this answer for you :-)